# Find all perfect squares of the form $17p + 1$ where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

So this is what I have, and I know it is incomplete. I know $p = 19$ is the only prime for which $17p + 1$ is a perfect square but I can't seem to find the connection.

**Proof**. That is, $$17p + 1 = (x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1\\ \implies 17p = x^2 + 2x = x(x + 2),$$ and we see that $17p$  can be written as a product of primes, which is unique. We can therefore see that $p = 19$ applies here.

Comment: What do you mean connection?

Comment: I can't just say p = 19 is the only one, I need to show that for all others it doesn't apply, correct?

Comment: I don't think the word "connection" means what you think it does.

Comment: I figured it out, although troubling, worth while. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use what you have already to finish the proof.

Since $17p = x(x+2)$ and $x \neq 1$, for $p$ to be prime one of the factors must be $17$ and the other must be $p$.

You already saw the case where $x = 17$. If $x+2 = 17$, then $x = 15$, but $15$ is not prime, so $p = 19$ is the only solution.

Here's another way you could solve it:

If $n^2 = 17p + 1$, then $n \equiv 1, 16 \pmod {17}$

Case $1$: $n = 17m + 1$. Then $289m^2 + 34m + 1 = 17p + 1$ so $p = m(17m + 2)$. One of these factors must be equal to $1$, so $m = 1$ and $p = 19$.

Case $2$: $n = 17m - 1$. Then similarly $p = m(17m - 2)$, so $m = 1$, but then $p = 15$ which is not prime.

Answer (score 3):

If $17p + 1 = n^2,$ then $(n-1)(n+1) = 17p,$ so the only possibilities are $n-1 = 17$ or $n+1 = 17.$

Answer (score 3):

you have two choices
$$
x=17, p=x+2=19,\\
x+2=17, p=x=15
$$
second is not possible.